# Prevent Django i18n_patterns from using dash as prefix separator

Tags: django, url, internationalization, url-pattern, django-i18n

[Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/translation/#django.conf.urls.i18n.i18n_patterns) states that i18n_patterns uses the forward slash as prefix separator for language codes. So, the URL `/en/id-123` activates English as language, while `/id/id-123` activates Indonesian.

However, it seems that the dash is also used as a separator, because the URL `/id-123` also activates Indonesian as language. But that's undesired in my use case, because this URL should only fetch an object with `ID = 123` instead of switching the language.

Is there some setting for determining this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have misdiagnosed the issue.  It is very unlikely that Django parses the dash in the URL.  I suspect that /id-123 uses Indonesian because that’s the default language in the settings, or the request language determined from your browser settings.